# How to move the data to the next line based on spaces in sqlserver 2008 R2

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

Input : Keep the column value into next line if word to word space is 3 space and length of the word is >9 .

```
declare @Table table(CL1 varchar(50))
    INSERT INTO @Table
    SELECT 'Ohh   my GOD'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'hindunewspaer is no1 paper'

select * from @Table
```

o/p :

### CL1

```
ohh
my god
hindunewpaer
is no1 paper
```

Answer (score 0):

Used a Split/Parse function.  Can be inline if needed.

> **EDIT -** Switch to a Parser which is not limited to 8K because the final
>   string could easily be larger than 8K

**Example**

```
;with cte0 as (
        Select Seq=Row_Number() over (Order by (Select null)),RetSeq,RetVal
         From  @Table A
         Cross Apply ( 
                      Select RetSeq
                            ,RetVal=case when len(RetVal)>9 then '~~~' else '' end+RetVal+case when len(RetVal)>9 then '~~~' else '' end
                       From  [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](Replace(CL1,'   ','~~~ '),' ') 
                    ) B ),
      cte1 as ( Select S=Stuff((Select ' '+RetVal From  cte0 Order by Seq For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') )                   
Select CL1 = RetVal
 From  cte1 A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse](A.S,'~~~') B
 Order By RetSeq
```

**Returns**

```
CL1
Ohh
my GOD
hindunewspaer
is no1 paper
```

**The Split/Parse Function if Needed**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
          ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Thanks Shnugo for making this XML safe
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('this,is,<test>,for,< & >',',')
```